# How do I get a Dane-Elec mp3/mp4 player working?

Tags: hardware, music, mp3, mp3-player, mp4

My MP3/MP4 does not plug-in and play and therefore I can not transfer any file to the MP3/MP4 [dane-elec music my touch](http://www.dane-elec.fr/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=24&lang=en) or only dane-elec with 8 gb in memory and perhapses model zt1 with radio,..and microsdhc card slot

following the above link the mp3/mp4 is there and it is MP3 Player: TOUCH MY MUSIC and the complete information is on this site http://www.danedigital.com/8-Music-Media-Players/2-music-touch.html as the Technical Specifications

MP3 Player: TOUCH MY MUSIC The Mp4 player has a very classy. It allows its users to play music and view photos and video. His fluent interface, its touch-pad, his radio and RDS Micro SDHC reader makes him a very complete device will become the ideal musical companion.

ubuntu i am with is ubuntu 11.10 kernel 3.0.0-14-generic the latest

I tried to install many applications but nothing worked.

With disk utility I can see that Ubuntu can recognize something, that as a peripheral device named `rockchip usbdisk user` and `rockchip usbdisk sd`,

and i can plug and play other devices, and only this mp3/mp4 do not connect to the computer with ubuntu and the device as no problem working disconnected to computer

I try to see if work on Windows and it does! I can see the device and transfer files to the MP3/MP4 dane-elec folder device and use FAT32. So why can not do on Ubuntu!?

What can I do and why does not work on Ubuntu? What is wrong with it?

Here are the logs:

```
Jan  4 17:27:34 a-ubuntu kernel: [  141.948863] init: apport pre-start process (1970) terminated with status 1
Jan  4 17:27:34 a-ubuntu kernel: [  141.963202] init: apport post-stop process (1994) terminated with status 1
Jan  4 17:30:02 a-ubuntu kernel: [  289.564049] usb 2-4: new high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:30:02 a-ubuntu kernel: [  289.988706] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jan  4 17:30:02 a-ubuntu kernel: [  289.992056] Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
Jan  4 17:30:02 a-ubuntu kernel: [  289.992272] scsi6 : usb-storage 2-4:1.0
Jan  4 17:30:02 a-ubuntu kernel: [  289.993082] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jan  4 17:30:02 a-ubuntu kernel: [  289.993088] USB Mass Storage support registered.
Jan  4 17:30:03 a-ubuntu kernel: [  290.996887] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     RockChip USBDISK  User    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Jan  4 17:30:03 a-ubuntu kernel: [  290.997372] scsi 6:0:0:1: Direct-Access     RockChip USBDISK    SD    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Jan  4 17:30:03 a-ubuntu kernel: [  290.997478] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:03 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.002712] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:03 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.002880] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.016249] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.032252] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.048182] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.060178] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.060357] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.080381] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.080646] sd 6:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.088381] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 16015360 512-byte logical blocks: (8.19 GB/7.63 GiB)
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.088988] sd 6:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.200050] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.448044] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.696055] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.832046] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.832994] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.833001] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.834378] sdb: detected capacity change from 8199864320 to 0
Jan  4 17:30:04 a-ubuntu kernel: [  291.835367] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jan  4 17:30:06 a-ubuntu kernel: [  293.004741] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 16015360 512-byte logical blocks: (8.19 GB/7.63 GiB)
Jan  4 17:30:06 a-ubuntu kernel: [  293.116051] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:30:21 a-ubuntu kernel: [  308.228043] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan  4 17:30:36 a-ubuntu kernel: [  323.444072] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan  4 17:30:36 a-ubuntu kernel: [  323.660047] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:30:51 a-ubuntu kernel: [  338.772085] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:06 a-ubuntu kernel: [  353.988064] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:07 a-ubuntu kernel: [  354.204058] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:31:12 a-ubuntu kernel: [  359.224115] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:17 a-ubuntu kernel: [  364.344136] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:17 a-ubuntu kernel: [  364.560037] usb 2-4: reset high speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:31:22 a-ubuntu kernel: [  369.580132] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.700126] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804121] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 3
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804518] sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804600] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804606] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804693] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] READ CAPACITY failed
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804698] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804704] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804744] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804748] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.804754] sdb: detected capacity change from 8199864320 to 0
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.820273] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.852240] scsi: killing requests for dead queue
Jan  4 17:31:27 a-ubuntu kernel: [  374.980054] usb 2-4: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
Jan  4 17:31:43 a-ubuntu kernel: [  390.092059] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:58 a-ubuntu kernel: [  405.308070] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Jan  4 17:31:58 a-ubuntu kernel: [  405.524078] usb 2-4: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
```

and the other post is:

- http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/792915/

and the other

bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04f2 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0xb008 USB 2.0 Camera
  bcdDevice           93.27
  iManufacturer           2 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd.
  iProduct                1 Chicony USB 2.0 Camera
  iSerial                 3 SN0001
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          565
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bFunctionProtocol       0 
      iFunction               1 Chicony USB 2.0 Camera
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              1 Chicony USB 2.0 Camera
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                13
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      1 (HEADER)
        bcdUVC               1.00
        wTotalLength           77
        dwClockFrequency       15.000000MHz
        bInCollection           1
        baInterfaceNr( 0)       1
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             2
        wTerminalType      0x0101 USB Streaming
        bAssocTerminal          0
        bSourceID               4
        iTerminal               0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                26
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
        bUnitID                 4
        guidExtensionCode         {7033f028-1163-2e4a-ba2c-6890eb334016}
        bNumControl             1
        bNrPins                 1
        baSourceID( 0)          3
        bControlSize            1
        bmControls( 0)       0x01
        iExtension              0 
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                18
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
        bTerminalID             1
        wTerminalType      0x0201 Camera Sensor
        bAssocTerminal          0
        iTerminal               0 
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMin      0
        wObjectiveFocalLengthMax      0
        wOcularFocalLength            0
        bControlSize                  3
        bmControls           0x00000000
      VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                11
        bDescriptorType        36
        bDescriptorSubtype      5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
      Warning: Descriptor too short
        bUnitID                 3
        bSourceID               1
        wMaxMultiplier          0
        bControlSize            2
        bmControls     0x0000053f
          Brightness
          Contrast
          Hue
          Saturation
          Sharpness
          Gamma
          Backlight Compensation
          Power Line Frequency
        iProcessing             0 
        bmVideoStandards     0x a
          NTSC - 525/60
          SECAM - 625/50
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            14
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  1 (INPUT_HEADER)
        bNumFormats                         1
        wTotalLength                      345
        bEndPointAddress                  129
        bmInfo                              0
        bTerminalLink                       2
        bStillCaptureMethod                 0
        bTriggerSupport                     1
        bTriggerUsage                       0
        bControlSize                        1
        bmaControls( 0)                    27
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            27
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFormatIndex                        1
        bNumFrameDescriptors                7
        guidFormat                            {59555932-0000-1000-8000-00aa00389b71}
        bBitsPerPixel                      16
        bDefaultFrameIndex                  1
        bAspectRatioX                       0
        bAspectRatioY                       0
        bmInterlaceFlags                 0x00
          Interlaced stream or variable: No
          Fields per frame: 2 fields
          Field 1 first: No
          Field pattern: Field 1 only
          bCopyProtect                      0
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            46
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         1
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            640
        wHeight                           480
        dwMinBitRate                   614400
        dwMaxBitRate                 18432000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      614400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  5
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 3)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            46
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         2
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            352
        wHeight                           288
        dwMinBitRate                   202752
        dwMaxBitRate                  6082560
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      202752
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  5
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 3)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            46
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         3
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            320
        wHeight                           240
        dwMinBitRate                   153600
        dwMaxBitRate                  4608000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize      153600
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  5
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 3)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            46
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         4
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            176
        wHeight                           144
        dwMinBitRate                    50688
        dwMaxBitRate                  1520640
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       50688
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  5
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 3)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            46
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         5
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                            160
        wHeight                           120
        dwMinBitRate                    38400
        dwMaxBitRate                  1152000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize       38400
        dwDefaultFrameInterval         333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  5
        dwFrameInterval( 0)            333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)            500000
        dwFrameInterval( 2)            666666
        dwFrameInterval( 3)           1000000
        dwFrameInterval( 4)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         6
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                           800
        dwMinBitRate                  2048000
        dwMaxBitRate                 18432000
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     2048000
        dwDefaultFrameInterval        1333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                            34
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                  5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
        bFrameIndex                         7
        bmCapabilities                   0x00
          Still image unsupported
        wWidth                           1280
        wHeight                          1024
        dwMinBitRate                  2621440
        dwMaxBitRate                 23592960
        dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize     2621440
        dwDefaultFrameInterval        1333333
        bFrameIntervalType                  2
        dwFrameInterval( 0)           1333333
        dwFrameInterval( 1)           2000000
      VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
        bLength                             6
        bDescriptorType                    36
        bDescriptorSubtype                 13 (COLORFORMAT)
        bColorPrimaries                     1 (BT.709,sRGB)
        bTransferCharacteristics            1 (BT.709)
        bMatrixCoefficients                 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0080  1x 128 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0100  1x 256 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0320  1x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0b20  2x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x1320  3x 800 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       6
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            5
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               Asynchronous
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x13e8  3x 1000 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 ?
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Interface Association
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Bus 006 Device 002: ID 04d9:1503 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Shortboard Lefty
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04d9 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
  idProduct          0x1503 Shortboard Lefty
  bcdDevice            3.10
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2 USB Keyboard
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           59
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      62
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.10
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     101
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              10
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

Comment: Are you asking about support for transferring files to a specific device?  MP3 and MP4 files should be playable by Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add what model of mp3/mp4 player you have?

Comment: yes, to a device , hardware.. and i can play mp3 and mp4 file that is not the issue.

Comment: i am not sure if i am asking to the question about the model of the device but saying it all is a mp3/mp4 device named dane-elec music my touch or only dane-elec with 8 gb in memory and perhapses model zt1

Comment: can anybody explain to me why is not working the mp3/mp4 ?

Comment: following the above link the mp3/mp4 is there and it is MP3 Player: TOUCH MY MUSIC and the complete information is on this site http://www.danedigital.com/8-Music-Media-Players/2-music-touch.html

Comment: Hi - my fault, but `lsusb` should be run as `sudo lsusb`. Also, what version of Ubuntu is this?  Finally, you should include your kernel version with `uname -r`.

Comment: does anybody know why mp3/mp4 do not work on ubuntu ?and what can be done?

Comment: ubuntu 10.10 kernel 3.0.0-14-generic

Comment: MP3/MP4 works fine on Ubuntu - your issue here is that Dane-Elec appear to use a proprietary connection method, so Ubuntu isn't recognising the device properly.  Perhaps try the latest version of Ubuntu using a live-CD or live-USB and see if that "sees" the Dane-Elec device.  If it does, either upgrade Ubuntu, or maybe try loading the latest Kernel using a PPA.

Comment: i am not sure if you are suggesting using the next ubuntu release 12.04 or 11.04 the current one. i mistaken have wrote that i was with 10.10 ubuntu but i am with ubuntu 11.04 kernel 3.0.0-14-generic and with this ubuntu don't work i also have try with 11.04 and did not work.so with ubuntu 11.10 with latest updates is not working, i do know with 12.04

Comment: 12.04 isn't out yet, but you could still create a Live-USB from the beta image - no risk in doing so (assuming you don't install it).  It's probably your best shot, unless someone know where to find firmware for your player.

Comment: how can i download ubuntu 12.04 i can only find 11.10 and 10.04.can you give me the link to the beta page?

Comment: Can you also give the output of: lsusb When the device is attached. Have you tried Banshee / Rhythmnbox to see if it is detected there?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I can help get this working, but this will help troubleshoot the issue.

1. Unplug the device
2. Start a terminal (search for "terminal" in the Dash)
3. Type `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` into the terminal and press return.
4. Plug in your Dane-elec MP3 player.
5. Post the results into your question

You should also run `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lsusb -v` while the device is plugged in and post the results of that into your question too.

From the Linux USB FAQ : http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html#ts6, you might want to try forcing the device to only connect at USB1.1 speeds.  In a terminal, run the command `rmmod ehci-hcd` then reconnect your device.

That FAQ also suggests that some motherboards will benefit from being started with "pci-noacpi" or "acpi=off" as boot option.  Another suggested a "noapic" option.  These are GRUB options - out with my expertise, but perhaps this site links to other answers that might help.

Comment: rmmod ehci-hcd send this error, ERROR: Module ehci_hcd does not exist in /proc/modules

Comment: how i change boot options to one of those

Comment: Did you try that command with sudo?

Comment: yes and have give the same error  ERROR: Module ehci_hcd does not exist in /proc/modules

Comment: does anybody as another suggestion?