# Why doesn't my mp3/mp4 player work on Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, music, mp3, mp3-player, mp4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a Dane-Elec mp3/mp4 player working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92623/how-do-i-get-a-dane-elec-mp3-mp4-player-working)

My MP3/MP4 does not plug-in and play and therefore I can not transfer any file to the MP3/MP4 dane-elec music my touch or only dane-elec with 8 gb in memory and perhapses model zt1 with radio,..and microsdhc card slot

following the above link the mp3/mp4 is there and it is MP3 Player: TOUCH MY MUSIC and the complete information is on this site http://www.danedigital.com/8-Music-Media-Players/2-music-touch.html as the Technical Specifications

MP3 Player: TOUCH MY MUSIC The Mp4 player has a very classy. It allows its users to play music and view photos and video. His fluent interface, its touch-pad, his radio and RDS Micro SDHC reader makes him a very complete device will become the ideal musical companion.

I tried to install many applications but nothing worked.

With disk utility I can see that Ubuntu can recognize something, that as a peripheral device named rockchip usbdisk user and rockchip usbdisk sd,

and i can plug and play other devices, and only this mp3/mp4 do not connect to the computer with ubuntu and the device as no problem working disconnected to computer

I try to see if work on Windows and it does! I can see the device and transfer files to the MP3/MP4 dane-elec folder device and use FAT32. So why can not do on Ubuntu!?

What can I do and why does not work on Ubuntu? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, just keep editing and improving your existing question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a file to the root partition of the device called **.is_audio_file** this shows the capabilities of the device. So for my Sansa clip this contains:

```
audio_folders=MUSIC/,PODCASTS/,AUDIOBOOKS/
output_formats=application/ogg,audio/mpeg,audio/flac,audio/x-ms-wma,audio/aac,audio/mp4,audio/audible
input_formats=application/ogg,audio/mpeg,audio/flac,audio/x-ms-wma,audio/aac,audio/mp4,audio/audible
folder_depth=1
playlist_path=PLAYLISTS/%File
playlist_format=audio/x-iriver-pla
```

It is important that the file is in the root directory of the device, and the name starts with a "."

Comment: i can not understand what i have to do or how can i do this because i do not know where to find that file .is_audio_file to add to the device and i can not open the folder of the device cause ubuntu don't recognize can you explain better